# Forcing $2^{\omega} = \omega_{\omega_1}$ together with $2^{\omega_1} = \omega_{\omega_2}$

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals, forcing

I'm studying from Kunen's *Set Theory*, and I came across this exercise (G6 ch. 7):

> Suppose $M$ satisfies $\text{GCH}$. Let $\kappa_1 < \dots < \kappa_n$ be regular cardinals of $M$ and let $\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le\dots\le\lambda_n$ be cardinals of $M$ such that $(\text{cof}(\lambda_i)>\kappa_i)^M$.  Force $n$ times to construct a c.t.m (countable transitive model) $N\supset M$ with the same cardinals such that for each $i$, $(2^{\kappa_i} = \lambda_i)^N$.

Now, I have some problems in proving this in its generality. I'll exemplify this:
suppose I want to show the general statement above for $n = 2, \kappa_1 = \omega, \kappa_2 = \omega_1, \lambda_1 = \omega_{\omega_1}, \lambda_2 = \omega_{\omega_2}$.

I would first use the forcing notion $\mathbb{P}_1 = \text{Fn}(\omega_{\omega_2}\times \omega_1, 2, \omega_1)$. In fact, by taking a $\mathbb{P}_1$-general filter $G$ over M, we have that $M[G]$ preserves cardinals and, thanks to $\text{GCH}$ in $M$, we also have  $(2^{\omega_1} = \omega_{\omega_2})^{M[G]}$.

Secondly I'd use (inside $M[G]$) the forcing notion $\mathbb{P}_2 = \text{Fn}(\omega_{\omega_1}\times \omega, 2, \omega)$.  Since $(\mathbb{P}_2 \text{ ccc})^{M[G]}$, this second forcing preserves cardinals. A problem arises when we want to show that $(2^\omega = \omega_{\omega_1})^{M[G][Q]}$ with $Q$ a $\mathbb{P}_2$-generic filter over $M[G]$.
Of course we have $(2^\omega \ge \omega_{\omega_1})^{M[G][Q]}$ but to show also 
$(2^\omega \le \omega_{\omega_1})^{M[G][Q]}$ we need to deal with nice names in $\mathbb{P}_2$. By doing so we get $(2^{\omega} \le \theta)^{M[G][Q]}$ with $(\theta = \omega_{\omega_1}^\omega)^{M[G]}$. So we are left  to prove $(\omega_{\omega_1}^\omega \le \omega_{\omega_1})^{M[G]}$. But I don't see how to do this.

If we were to continue , we would still need show that $(2^{\omega_1} = \omega_{\omega_2})^{M[G][Q]}$:

of course I have $(2^{\omega_1} \ge \omega_{\omega_2})^{M[G][Q]}$ since we are preserving cardinals and this holds trivially in $M[G]$.
To show that $(2^{\omega_1} \le \omega_{\omega_2})^{M[G][Q]}$ I'd again use the nice names within $\mathbb{P}_2$, and this gives us $(2^{\omega_1} \le \theta)^{M[G][Q]}$ where $(\theta = \omega_{\omega_1}^{\omega_1})^{M[G]}$.

Hence the final argument would be to prove that $(\omega_{\omega_1}^{\omega_1} \le \omega_{\omega_2})^{M[G]}$, but again I don't see how to do this. Any hint?

Thanks!

EDIT: I noticed that the problem was arising also in the midst of the proof, so I added it and simply rescaled everything by one cardinals to make it "simpler".

---

EDIT2: If you don't want to understand my try, it's ok of course. I'd be obliged if you just mention how you would prove it, regardless of what I did! I'm referring to the original exercise I quoted or the more specific one I proposed.

EDIT3: As someone pointed out, the first forcing is $\omega_1$-closed, hence we have $(\omega_{\omega_1}^\omega)^M = (\omega_{\omega_1}^\omega)^{M[G]}$. Therefore the first thing is solved. It remains the second one (i.e. $(\omega_{\omega_1}^{\omega_1} \le \omega_{\omega_2})^{M[G]}$)

Thanks again

Comment: @NoahSchweber . I am very rusty on this. What if, in the Q, we replace $\Bbb P_2$ with $Fn(\omega_{\omega_3}\times \omega_1,2, \omega_1)?$

Comment: @NoahSchweber But then how can I guarantee the preservation of cardinals? By doing what you are suggesting I would have $(2^{<\omega_2} =\omega_{\omega_2} > \omega_2)^{M[G]}$, hence I would loose control over the cardinals between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_{\omega_2}$...

Comment: At least this is the reason why Kunen always forces from the largest cardinal to the lowest.

Comment: @Lorenzo Derp, ignore me.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I think you'd get $2^{\omega_1}=2^{\omega_2}=\omega_{\omega_3}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber . $2^{\omega_2}=$ $\omega_{\omega_3}\implies$ $ \omega_{\omega_2}+2^{\omega_2}=$ $\max (\omega_{\omega_2}, 2^{\omega_2})=$ $\max(\omega_{\omega_2},\omega_{\omega_3})=$ $\omega_{\omega_3}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes? Is that a problem? (I haven't had my coffee yet so I could easily be missing something.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber . No. I'm just being pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first forcing is $\omega_1$-closed, there are no new mappings $\omega\to M,$ so the set of mappings $\omega\to \omega_{\omega_1}$ is the same in $M[G]$ as in $M$ and so since cardinals are preserved, $$(\omega_{\omega_1}^{\omega})^{M[G]} = (\omega_{\omega_1}^{\omega})^{M}=\omega_{\omega_1}.$$

For the other missing part, just observe that in $M[G]$, $$ \omega_{\omega_1} <\omega_{\omega_2} = 2^{\omega_1},$$ so $$  \omega_{\omega_1}^{\omega_1} = 2^{\omega_1} = \omega_{\omega_2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Isn't the first forcing just $\omega_1$ closed?

Comment: @Lorenzo Yes, whoops.

Comment: @Lorenzo yep, what I had before for the second part made no sense at all now that I think about it... but I think my latest edit works.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you say $\omega_{\omega_1}^{\omega_1}=2^{\omega_1}$ (in $M[G]$)?

Comment: Since ${\omega_{\omega_1}} < 2^{\omega_1}$, so $$ 2^{\omega_1} \le \omega_{\omega_1}^{\omega_1}\le (2^{\omega_1})^{\omega_1}\le 2^{\omega_1}.$$